# Is there a word for the act of subduing something?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm referring to military forces subduing another group of military forces. Subduction is what I initially thought of but that specifically refers to the geological process involving tectonic plates. I'm trying to say that "the ... (act of subduing) the x guard was legitimate and legal" but was hoping for a word (like subduction except it doesn't mean what I want it to mean) instead of a phrase. Thank you!

Comment: What specific sense of [*subdue*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subdue) are you thinking of? Several could fit, even when talking about military forces. Don't just say *act of subduing*. Describe it differently, such as with a synonym for the sense you want.

Comment: In fact, if you look at synonyms for [*subdue*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/subdue), you'll find many words that could fit whatever sense you mean and also be turned into nouns.

Comment: You can use the verbal noun "subduing" - The **subduing** of the Red Guard was legitimate and legal".

Comment: What document legalizes your example? I'd stick with situations and wording that are given in one of the better just war documents. [Jus ad bellum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_ad_bellum), [Tyrannicide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrannicide)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have answered your own question:

> I'm trying to say that "the ... (act of subduing) the x guard was legitimate and legal"

**Subduing**

"The **subduing of** the x guard was legitimate and legal."

In that sentence, "subduing" acts as a verbal noun.

Or

"**Subduing** the x guard was legitimate and legal."

In that sentence, "subduing" acts as a gerund.

Both express the action of their verb.

Answer (score 0):

**Subjugation**:

- *the action of bringing someone or something under domination or control.*

Answer (score 0):

"**Subordination**" is an act.

> **Subordination:**
>
> : placement in a lower class, rank, or position : the act or process of subordinating someone or something or the state of being subordinated.
>
> //The price is individual subordination to the group and limited autonomy of the nuclear family.— Corinne N. Nydegger
>
> //After 1688, as before, the message was one of subordination to divinely constituted authority, whether of kings or of one's social superiors.— Richard W. Davis
>
> Since 1595, according to https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subordination

From

> **subordinate** (Entry 3 of 3) transitive verb
>
> 1: to make subject or subservient.
>   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subordinate#h3

Answer (score 0):

The language of power relationships is complex and highly nuanced, since different audiences must be addressed in different ways.  The sting of defeat must sometimes be mitigated. The sacrifices needed to achieve victory must be often be expressed heroically, and a veil of nobility and high purpose drawn over the most squalid details.

If your intent is to be as objective and “morally neutral” as possible, you can refer to the guard being **neutralized**.

Your use of “legitimate and legal” is already placing a moral framework around the use of violence by one group against another. Your choice of words for the action of subduing the guard can therefore be used to intensify or attenuate the moral framework, depending on the audience you are intending to reach.

A lot here depends on what you mean by “military force”, and the circumstances under which the engagement took place. An encounter between commandos and regular forces in a state of war between two powerful nations is different from an armed gang forcing its way into a government office in a nation undergoing an insurrection.